# Collect catch processing in one method

Tags: c#, exception

.Net Framework version: 3.5

I have a program that processes all exceptions that can be generated. This results in a large number of catch blocks, many of which are duplicates from one method to another. I would like to collect all of the catch processing into a single method. For example:

```
string catch_processing ( Exception  e )
    {

    }
```

In this example, the method would return the `e.Message` and the `e.StackTrace` and any other information that was pertinent. It's that "other information" that is my problem. I want to differentiate between exceptions, something like

```
switch ( e )
    {
    case PathTooLongException:
        :
        break;

    case DirectoryNotFoundException:
        :
        break;

    default:
        :
        break;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to implement this method and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for, but it sounds like you're doing something wrong if you have that many catch blocks. You should only catch exceptions that you can handle.

Comment: You can always just rethrow `e` and catch and handle it inside `CatchProcessing()` to distinguish the type. (It's ugly, but if you're bent on this approach, why not.) That said, this *might* clobber the stack trace, so you might want to handle that before.

Comment: @brian The program requires that all exceptions be reported, whether or not they are handled.

Comment: @millimoose The question was how to handle it inside CatchProcessing()

Comment: Even if that is the case, there's no reason to catch exception in all methods.

Comment: How are you going to report an exception that is unhandled, when you are handling them in order to report them?

Comment: @Gaus That's what I meant. You can rethrow the `e` parameter like: `try { throw e; } catch PathTooLongException {...} ...` - and make use of how `try..catch` matches the exception to the type.

Comment: @millimoose Why didn't I think of that? Makes the whole thing simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Soundarajan, I've implemented the answer as:

```
    static string catch_processing ( Exception  e )
        {
        StringBuilder   sb = new StringBuilder ( );

        try 
            { 
            throw e; 
            } 
        catch ( PathTooLongException )
            {
            sb.Append (
                "Supplied path is longer than the system-" +
                "defined maximum length" );
            }
        catch ( ArgumentException )
            {
            sb.Append (
                "Supplied path contains invalid characters, " +
                "is empty, or contains only white spaces" );
            }
        catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException )
            {
            sb.Append (
                "The caller does not have the " +
                "required permission" );
            }
        : other catch blocks

        sb.AppendFormat ( "{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                          Environment.NewLine,
                          e.Message,
                          Environment.NewLine,
                          e.StackTrace );

        return ( sb.ToString ( ) );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`TryCatchLog`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11999/) static method was posted to CodeReview that does what I think you're trying to do; `exceptionSubscriber.TryCatchLog(Statements...)` would catch any exceptions thrown by `Statements...`, log them to `exceptionSubscriber`, and rethrow.

Before you copy that code, however, stop and explain what you are trying to accomplish. "The program requires that all exceptions be reported" is a very suspicious statement since the runtime will already report unhandled exceptions without you doing anything. Another very suspicious thing is that there are no `throw` statements in your `catch_processing`.

You're not trying to continue after any exception has been thrown, are you? Take it from a veteran of the `ON ERROR GOTO` days that is a mistake; programs that try to continue after an exception have a tendency to fail and be very hard to debug. They will throw an exception, keep going, show wrong results, keep going, corrupt data, keep going, then start a cascade of errors which all get logged, keep going, fill your disk, keep going, lock up machines, keep going, until they finally go into an infinite loop. Have fun debugging that.

Answer (score 1):

If reporting the exception is your only goal, you could perhaps try out the following

```
public class Foo
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
     domain.FirstChanceException += new EventHandler<FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs>(CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException);
  }

   static void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
       //If you are not putting this inside a try finally block then this would become an infinite recursion.
        try
        {
            var actualException = args.Exception;
            Console.WriteLine(actualException.ToString());
            //Do whatever with actualException

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just mentioned it inside main for the sake of explaining. put that piece of code in an appropriate place where the application initialization happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use instanceof to determine what type of exception it is.  Like others have commented, I think you need to rethink your exception handling strategy.

Comment: The program requires that all exceptions be reported, whether or not they are handled

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any of that:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += SomeExceptionHandler;`

is going to handle any and all exceptions that occur in the `AppDomain` scope (which is basically the entire application if you're not dealing with multiple `AppDomain`s.

Then, instead of trying to obtain the Exception type in a strongly-typed manner (such as casting to `"System.XXXXException` or `"System.YYYYException"`), use Reflection to obtain the whole object graph of the exception objects and you can log that (or do whatever error reporting you want).